# Can't Get Android ListView Working Properly

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, android-listview

I'm try to make a `ListView` for my app, but I am getting the following answer

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

This problem appears when I successfully put the `ListView` working but it won't updated after add or remove data mysq sqlite database.

My `ListView` code;

```
MessageRepo repo = new MessageRepo(this);
msgsList =  repo.getMessageList();
lv = getListView();
ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, msgsList);
setListAdapter(arrayAdapter);
arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();//my second problem
```

getMessageList() code:

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>  getMessageList() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        String selectQuery =  "SELECT  " +
                Message.KEY_ID + "," +
                Message.KEY_message +
                " FROM " + Message.TABLE;

        //Message Message = new Message();
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MessageList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // looping through all rows and adding to list

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                HashMap<String, String> Messagehash = new HashMap<String, String>();
                Messagehash.put("id", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Message.KEY_ID)));
                Messagehash.put("message", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Message.KEY_message)));
                MessageList.add(Messagehash);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return MessageList;

    }
```

Listview xml code:

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is to create an Adapter that extends an ArrayAdapter
like this:

```
private class StableArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    HashMap<String, Integer> mIdMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    public StableArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        Cursor cameFromDB) {
      super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
      for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i) {
        //Put your cursor logic here
      }
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
      String item = getItem(position);
      return mIdMap.get(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
      return true;
    }

  }

}
```

Your XML should be like this:

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**You can use a custom layout with ListActivity or ListFragment. In this case the fragment or activity searches in the provided layout for a ListView with the pre-defined android:id attribute set to @android:id/list.**